# Собственный разборщик условий (interpreter)

Tags: php, cms

Доброго вам вечера товарищи! Месяц назад я задавал этот вопрос, однако слишком плохо его расписал, сегодня постараюсь исправить ошибки и спросить ещё раз.

Я разрабатываю собственную **CMS-систему**, которая будет использована для создания собственных проектов, а также эта система будет доступна друзьям для их проектов. В "свет" эта система не выйдет, 95%, что это так и будет.

Далеко не в каждой современной **CMS-системе** присутствует то, что нужно под мои личные нужды, а также порой есть то, что вовсе является лишней нагрузкой.

У меня собственный шаблонизатор(если его так можно назвать:D), который вытаскивает из переданного ему **HTML-кода** **специальные метки**.

**Специальные метки** - это текст вида **(:[languages;users;registration_invitation;<>;2{users#session=1};]:)** , используется для того, чтобы указать шаблонизатору на некую последовательность команд, результат выполнения которых нужно записать заместо метки.

Так выглядит простой шаблон с тремя метками :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>(:[build;index;title;<>;<>;]:)</title>
(:[build;index;header;<>;<>;]:)
</head>
<body>
(:[build;index;content;<>;<>;]:)
</body>
</html>
```

Структура метки :

(:[тип;владелец;имя;как_искать;условие_показа;]:)

Тип - указывает на тип содержимого для этой метки, например, у этой метки

**(:[languages;users;registration_invitation;<>;2{users#session=1};]:)**

тип **languages**, это говорит о том, что нам нужно использовать "инструмент" **tools_languages** для обработки этой метки.

**Владелец** - указывает на имя объекта в системе, к которому принадлежит метка.

**Имя** - название само говорит за себя, используется для указания на это место в документе.

**Как искать** - вспомогательный параметр, используется в сложных метках, если не нужен - пишем <>

**Условие показа** - здесь содержится условная конструкция, выполнение или невыполнение которой будет сообщать о необходимости обрабатывать эту метку или пропустить.

Вот мы и подошли к сути вопроса.

Дело в том, что мне крайне необходимо обрабатывать параметр **условие показа** метки, условие имеет вид :

**показывать или не показывать{имя_объекта#параметр оператор_сравнения значение}**

**имя_объекта** - это имя класса, к которому нужно обратиться.

**параметр** - это индекс в одном из массивов содержащихся в классе.

**оператор_сравнения** - это http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

**значение** - это значение, с которым будет сравниваться полученное значение из массива.

Всё бы ничего, но в **условии_показа** может быть не одно выражение, и сколько угодно скобок. Я пробовал написать свой разборщик, но всё обернулось потерей кучи времени и нулевым результатом.

**Собственно вопрос : как можно хранить некое условие с кучей выражений в виде обычного текста, а после обработать его так, чтобы** PHP **мог его понять и дать ответ?**

У меня был вариант : написать некий разборщик, который превратит

**(classname#param=value || classname#param=value) & classname#param!=value**

в

```
if (($expression_1 || $expression_2) & $expression_3) {
   $result  =  true;
} else {
   $result  =  false;
}
```

И с помощью **eval** выполнит его. Но это на крайний случай.

Comment: Вы там случаем ни `smarty` на свой лад пишите?

Comment: Я не знаю что такое smarty, единственное слышал, что это шаблонизатор.

Comment: too complicated...

Comment: Чем Вас так evel-то так пугает?

 Просто перед ним надо убедиться (в результате простого разбора на лексемы), что в eval Вы из своего условия подставляете только константы.

Comment: то что вы тут описали и является языком разметки шаблона :) т.е. шаблонизатором, что месяц назад, что сейчас одинаково непонятно зачем вы изобретаете свой велосипед и пытаетесь найти для спиц какую-то новую систему расстановки.

Comment: eicto, ибо мне не нужны чужие шаблонизаторы, свой я буду знать, смогу в любой момент править если это потребуется, в него я помещу всё, что только нужно и ничего лишнего. Вся эта новая разметка делает систему наиболее гибкой, чем остальные.

Comment: Андрей, я уже сейчас вижу что эта новая разметка очень сложна для понимания, и вероятно вы не пытались спланировать ваш язык разметки, а просто пишете по мере надобности, всё это приведет к языку код на котором будет похуже к пониманию чем [rfc822 regexp](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Выводы я делаю ввиду нестандартной терминологии которую вы используете для именования сущностей в логике своего парсера.

Comment: Неужто в этих загогулинах легче разбираться, нежели в простых php-вставках? Я еще понимаю, когда речь идет о ссылке на сниппет или вроде того, но когда эти «теги» превращаются в [[{{((::псевдо-условные-операторы-с-вызовом-функций-запросом-к-sql-возможностью-путешествия-во-времени::))}}]] — неужто это удобно?

Comment: вот если доделать шаблонизатор так, что бы он на основе этих шаблонов генерировал шаблоны для других популярных шаблонизаторов, того же smarty - вот это было бы интересней.

Comment: @KoVadim вы же знаете как это называется - Lisp :)

Comment: Язык разметки, ровно как и архитектура системы продуманы, в этом можете не сомневаться. Продумано всё до мелочей, я ведь не скидывал вам её код? Проблема встала только с разбором условий. В любом случае, даже если я изобретаю никому из вас не нужный велосипед, то это не значит, что я буду вам его "впихивать", мир то не сломается пополам. За советы - спасибо, порой они просто необходимы, но очень хочется услышать больше соображений по главному и пожалуй единственному вопросу.

Comment: Андрей, я не просто сомневаюсь, я **уверен**, что у вас ничего не продумано. Попробуйте написать спецификацию на свой шаблонизатор и дайте ее почитать знакомому программисту  (не обязательно при этом чтобы интерпретатор существовал в коде), попросите его реализовать какую нибудь задачу по его усмотрению, прочитайте что он напишет, спросите, почему он допустил ту или иную ошибку (всё это можно сделать и в голове, но нужно очень хорошо уметь эмулировать в голове себя не занимавшегося этой задачей)

Comment: @АндрейАршинов, этот вопрос, видимо, следовало задавать аккуратно, без упоминания о том что это будет **собственная CMS** :) Это и затмило заявление о том что «в "свет" эта система не выйдет, 95%».

И мне кажется, что `eval` здесь — лучший вариант.

А в качестве аргумента за «обыкновенные PHP-вставки» (это абсолютно не противоречит идеи *собственной CMS)* я предлагаю провести тест, который бы показал вам, как простой вызов функции/метода в PHP снижает производительность.

Comment: Bars, а если это будет только класс со статическим массивом?

Comment: > а если это будет только класс со статическим массивом?

Не понял.

Говоря о медлительности вызовов функций/методов, я имел в виду, что стоит посмотреть хотя бы на количество вызываемых функций при обработке таких вот меток. Навскидку (адекватный код): preg_replace_callback→callback→[ф-ция обработки]→[разбиение на операции]→[нормализация и проверка]→[выполнение операции].

Это может станет заметным «в бою».

Еще добавится [проверка условия], после чего цепь может продолжиться — при удовлетворительных условиях. Это против обычного вызова метода: `<?= ($rule == 1) ? $class->method() : ''; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаю новый "ответ" для обсуждения. Если использовать **PHP-вставки** в **HTML** файле, то этот файл нужно будет подключать с помощью **include**, или как-то по-другому можно обработать их и выполнить? Ведь очень много придётся написать в эту вставку :

<?php if (Marusya::States('0urlq') == '/view/home/1') { Marusya::a10('blocks', 'index', 'menu_top'); } ?>

Answer (score 3):

Вообще не вижу смысла в этом велосипеде.

Нужен шаблонизатор - есть смарти, писать свой - это по минимуму куча геморроя и тестирования производительности.

> ибо мне не нужны чужие шаблонизаторы,
> свой я буду знать, смогу в любой
> момент править если это потребуется, в
> него я помещу всё, что только нужно и
> ничего лишнего. Вся эта новая разметка
> делает систему наиболее гибкой, чем
> остальные.

Это все вода. Свой ты будешь знать, но он никогда не выйдет в свет - в этом ты прав, как и твой движок. Править можно любые шаблонизаторы! Лишнее в них тоже можно не использовать.

Вся эта разметка, только для тебя, никто другой в ней разбираться не будет на 100%.

> я уже сейчас вижу что эта новая
> разметка очень сложна для понимания, и
> вероятно вы не пытались спланировать
> ваш язык разметки, а просто пишете по
> мере надобности, всё это приведет к
> языку код на котором будет похуже к
> пониманию чем rfc822 regexp. Выводы я
> делаю ввиду нестандартной терминологии
> которую вы используете для именования
> сущностей в логике своего парсера.

Это правильно! Соглашусь со всем!

В общем даже для себя писать велосипеды - бывает намного хуже чем использовать уже существующие.

Comment: А ответа на вопрос не подскажете?

Comment: >> Собственно вопрос : как можно хранить некое условие с кучей выражений в виде обычного текста, а после обработать его так, чтобы PHP мог его понять и дать ответ?

думаю 

file.php

Comment: >А ответа на вопрос не подскажете?

Ответ на вопрос уже дан!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужны регекспы. Я использовал бы `preg_replace_callback`: это функция, выполняющая поиск и замену по регулярному выражению, причем замена происходит в пользовательской функции.

```
<?php
$text = "Два шаблона для примера:<br/><br/>Просто слова {user_func} <br/>Дата: {date}<br/>Неопределенный шаблон: {something}";

function vyr($matches){
  switch($matches[1]){
   case 'user_func':return 'Пользовательская замена';
   case 'current_date':return date("YmD");
   default:return $matches[0];
  }
  return $matches[1];
}

echo preg_replace_callback("/\{(.+)\}/u","vyr",$text);
?>
```

Писал на коленке, на работоспособность не проверял. Общий смысл, думаю, должен быть понятен. В регексп можно добавить, например, варианты через запятую. Почитайте о регулярных выражениях. Гуглу ведомо много статей по ним, и они, в общем, не так ужасны, как выглядят. Вот ссылки на официальный мануал:

- [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php)
- [Синтаксис регулярных выражений](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Успехов ;-)

Comment: думаю, у человека проблема немного не в этом:) собственно сам парсер шаблонов у него уже есть.